# Enable Gnome/GTK integration of IPython qtconsole from Anaconda

Tags: python, qt, pyside, gnome, anaconda

On a fresh install of Anaconda on my Debian testing system, the IPython Qtconsole from Anaconda has a poor appearance compared to the Qtconsole from Debian (see below) when running on a Gnome3 desktop. Other Qt-based GUIs like matplotlib windows are affected as well.

I suspect that the PySide Qt binding from Anaconda is not properly configured to use the system's Gnome/Gtk theme as the Qt from Debian does. In particular, default font size is affected which is quite annoying.

I'd glad to hear how to make Anaconda's PySide to use the proper Gnome theme.

[image]
(see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsXDw.png) for a larger image)

Comment: I have the same ugliness on ubuntu, it's not probably gnome 3 specific.

Comment: as a starting point, using the `qtconfig` utility shipped by Anaconda enables changing the default font for Qt apps (choosing for example Cantarell Regular). However, the "Desktop Settings" option of *Select GUI style* is not able to load the proper GTK theme used in Gnome, as opposed to the `qtconfig` shipped by Debian.

Comment: For the reference: a follow-up discussion on this issue has emerged on Continuum's forum : https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/anaconda/vFtZWAY4ylY/mCJxyrkc8_EJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the Continuum built qt doesn't have the correct libraries built into it. Can you try building `qt` from https://github.com/continuumio/conda-recipes, and see if it helps? You'll need a C compiler, and also various libraries installed (there is a `notes.md` file that lists all the packages you need to install). You'll also probably need to rebuild `shiboken` and `pyside` (in that order) against your new `qt`, since rebuilding `qt` tends to break ABI (at least in my experience).

Comment: Indeed @almarklein pointed out that the issue comes from a missing compilation flag "-gtkstyle". cf. https://github.com/ContinuumIO/conda-recipes/issues/22